# How to stop SSIS 2010 Script Task from ignoring breakpoints?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am working with an SSIS package in BIDS 2010/Visual Studio 2010. I have a script task that calls out to some .NET code. I have placed some breakpoints in this code, and can also see a breakpoint in the SSIS diagram. Whenever I debug the SSIS Package, it opens Visual Studio 2010 and ignores the breakpoints I have placed.

From what I have I read, I need to set a property on the project called "Run64BitRunTime" to false. I have done this, but it has no effect on resolving the problem. If I right click the Script Task and select "Edit Breakpoints", it shows my breakpoints checked with a Hit Count Type of "Always". However to SSIS, always means the exact opposite, because it never hits the breakpoints.

I have also tried setting the build to x86 in Visual Studio 2010, but again, that has had no effect.

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting the breakpoints by right clicking the task and adding breakpoints out of the available list or are you opening the script task and actually adding them to the line of the script?

Comment: Adding them to the line of the script, then verifying they show on the "Edit Breakpoints" screen you get when right clicking the task.

Comment: that is odd that they are being skipped... and I am assuming that you have already confirmed that your code is executing to the point of the breakpoint.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the very first line of the script task and catching it right as it starts just to confirm that it can be stopped?

Comment: I've found a workaround. I placed a MessageBox.Show(""); at the beginning. Once it hits this, I am able to click the "Break All" on the right hand side. Then I close the MessageBox, and hit F10.

Comment: @SFrejofsky Yeah, the first line of code has a breakpoint on it. Also confirmed the code was being hit by using the MessageBox.Show(...);

Comment: @Dave That's a strange behavior. Many a times when I faced the issue the reset of the flag in the properties does the trick i.e. Run64BitRunTime to false.Could you try putting breakpoints at multiple places apart from the first line and see? Also I hate to say this but some times restarting the application after setting the flag also worked. You can try that and check.